# Each time a number (health) decreased, execute a code

Tags: python

So basically I'm working on a python script to read health in a game. I use the following libraries.

```
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab
```

I have succeeded to read a health number in real-time screen and change  it to int in python. However, I still cannot come out with an idea on how to execute a code whenever my health in the game decreasing or in another term each time my health drop.

```
conf = r'--oem 3 --psm 6 outputbase digits'
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

def screenToData():
    while (True):
        screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(350, 150, 550, 300)))
        cv2.imshow("window", cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
        data = pytesseract.image_to_data(cv2.cvtColor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), lang='eng', config=conf)
        # print(data)
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

        for x, box in enumerate(data.splitlines()):
            if x != 0:
                box = box.split()
                # print(box)
                if len(box) == 12:
                    if int(box[11]) == 100:
                        print("Full health")
                    elif int(box[11]) <= 100:
                        print("Nope")


screenToData()
```

Comment: To be clear, you are trying to look at images of a *different, running program* and analyze them? And you have figured out how to check what the current health value is, and you are repeatedly doing this in a loop, but now you need to fix the code to check whether the value decreased since the last time you checked? Well.. did you consider using a variable to remember what the value was last time, and comparing to that value?

Comment: If you have this much code, using four different third-party libraries, and can't figure out the next small logical step, it suggests that you are taking a fundamentally wrong-headed approach to programming. Programming is about solving problems by thinking about them, not simply gluing together everyone else's work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step, in your code you should have a variable called health, this meakes the code more readable.

To determine when your health is dropping, each time you loop you just need to compare your current health to the last reading, so maybe add a variable new_health to compare to health.

```
health = 100

while True:
    new_health = read_health()
    if new_health < health:
        # execute code
    health = new_health
```